# jQuery serialize() throws empty string in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

jQuery `serialize()` throws empty string from a form, here is the source of the form

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/asdf" id="form_for_asdf_1_option_1" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="asdfaaqwefasdfwefefsefefwew=" /></div>
    <input name="checkbox_update_vote[asdf_id]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="dbr_1_of_asdf_1" name="checkbox_update_vote[asdf_id]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <input id="option_1_of_asdf_1" name="checkbox_update_vote[option_id]" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input id="del_1_of_asdf_1" name="checkbox_update_vote[del]" type="hidden" value="false" />
    <br />
</form>
```

and the JavaScript used to show the serialized output.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    alert($($(this).parents("form")[0].id).serialize());
  });
});
```

can some one point me where I am doing mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add '#':

```
$("#" + $(this).parents("form")[0].id)
```

Or remove `.id`:

```
$($(this).parents("form")[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `#` when looking for the form with the given id.

However, you could avoid this problem and simply use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the ancestor `<form>`

```
$(this).closest('form').serialize();
```